# PFQueryTableViewController crashes when accessing header view

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to implement a UISearchBar on a PFQueryTableViewController.
This is how I am doing it:

```
var filteredTableData = NSMutableArray()
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    // Configure the PFQueryTableView
    //self.parseClassName = "Collections"
    self.textKey = "username"
    self.imageKey = "profileImage"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = false
    self.paginationEnabled = true
    self.objectsPerPage = 20

        self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar
}
```

If I add the controller to the self.navigationItem.titleView, when I begin editing then the search bar slides up and the navigation bar disappears.
If instead I do:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar
```

the app crashes here:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
```

of PFQueryTableViewController.m

Comment: No sure but check http://codewithchris.com/using-parse-swift-xcode-6/ to configure an Obj-C Bridging Header

Comment: Hi, Did you find a way to use UISearchController in the PFQueryTableViewController?